# Google cloud natural language API adding own context classifier

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, google-natural-language

I have been searching how to create a new entity in google natural language API, and found nothing. Can anybody help how to create a new classifier such that if I pass a sentence and I want to detect suppose 'python' as programming language then how would I get that. Current the  API is giving 'python' as 'other'. [image: Google Cloud Natural Language API Response]

I have also looked into cloud auto ml api for my solution and tried to create and train a model but It was only able to do sentiment analysis not entity detection.It was giving me the score rather than telling me that Java is programming language. [image: trainedModel]
[image: Prediction]

Thanks in advance.Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you come to a solution? If yes, can you share it?

Answer (score 2):

Automl content classification classifies your data into the labels specified in the training set. It does not do entity detection. But it seems like what you need to do is closer to content classification than entity detection. My understanding from the description you provided is that you have content (may be words or phrases or short sentences) and you want to classify them into some labels (e.g. programmingLanguage). If you put together a good training set, the automl model should be able to do this.
The number it provides in eval is not sentiment, it's the probability of the predicted label. As you can see in the eval page you posted, it's telling you that java is a programmingLanguage with probability of 1 (so, it's very certain about it).